# How to create a clean url using apache and php?

Tags: php

I have build a basic blog application, where an admin can write the article in backend and the users can read it from frontend. i want to make my URL pretty so that it becomes SEO friendly. the url of the articles look like,

```
http://example.com/news.php?id=22
http://example.com/news.php?id=23
http://example.com/news.php?id=24
http://example.com/news.php?id=25
```

I want to make it clean and user or SEO friendly, what i want to achieve is in the news table in database i have a column name called title, and i want to display it as URI along with the combination of date. for example i want the URL to be like

> http://example.com/news/01092010/this-is-first-news-title

how do i do it. is there any article that might be of help to me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a beginners guide to `mod-rewrite`

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: i am testing my code on windows machine, using WAMP server, i am unable to create the .htaccess file in my www directory it asks for the file name.. what do i do?

Comment: Create .htaccess via FTP. Windows acts funny when you try to name a file like that.

Answer (score 5):

My recommendation is just to use mod-rewrite to direct everything to your index page using something like this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Then once everything is directed to your index create a [front controller](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/the_front_controller_and_php) that looks at the request and loads the appropriate page.

It's much simpler/easier to maintain than trying to do everything with mod rewrite

Comment: +1 for the front controller idea. I think this is the best way to handle it, especially if you have an MVC-style architecture.

Comment: do .htaccess rule apply to the sub directories too? i dont want the rule to be applied to sub directories.

Comment: You might want to add QSA to the end of that rule.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ModRewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

You can use maps to link id to text for instance