# How to make a PHP GET Request method like this "http://somesite.com/games/213123"?

Tags: php, url, indexing

Hi guys I'm wondering how to make this kind of requests to the server I looked at many sites and they use this technique. For example gametrailers.com => `http://www.gametrailers.com/video/level-six-diablo-iii/**721239**`. I know that a GET request is made by using parameters like this: `http://somesite.com/page.php?param=1`. So how to make it like gametrailers. I hope you understand my question and I doubt that "721239" is a folder on the server with an index page inside of it.

Comment: Ah, I would also like to know!

Comment: I have seen other language use it that way by default - such as MVC/.net

Comment: These are called clean URLs and there are hundreds if not thousands of duplicate questions about it. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clean+URLs

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You just type the URL differently, you don't have to do anything special.  The parsing of the arguments is done on the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a clean url using apache and php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620270/how-to-create-a-clean-url-using-apache-and-php)

Comment: Actually, it's not a GET request that's changed, but back-end parses the url and passes it to the processing script in a $_GET variable. Refer to `mod_rewrite` for Apache. A decent knowledge of regular expressions won't hurt.

Comment: Okay thank you, I really didn't know how that's called and therefore what to look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a file placed in the folder near your script with name **.htaccess**

In this file you need to define rewriting rules. The contents of the file are:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^games/(.*)$ games.php?id=$1 [L]
```

In this case
http://somesite.com/games/213123
will be transformed into http://somesite.com/games.php?id=213123

Comment: yeah, this works perfectly just remove the slash from "/games.php" =>"games.php"

Answer (score 2):

The more convinient way is to do [url rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine))

For example, you can have a .htaccess like this, well explained in [this guide](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/09-Links-and-the-Routing-System) from symfony:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # we skip all files with .something
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \..+$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  # we check if the .html version is here (caching)
  RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

  # no, so we redirect to our front web controller
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using MultiViews in Apache2 (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html).

MultiViews (when enabled) instructs Apache to build a parameter map when a resource doesn't exist, so for www.foo.com/app/game/14, if www.foo.com/app.php exists and app/game and app/game 14 don't, it can be set up to translate that to www.foo.com/app.php?type=game&article=14

Some people also use mod_rewrite, but I'm not sure that's the preferred approach.

Comment: Well I see that more people are suggesting mod_rewrite so I will go with it for now, Thank you anyway.